# table updates empty spaces when user do not enter anything to the textbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

i am doing a project where one may update the name, position, department and tag of the employee.

But as i do my project, it wont update, i know there is something wrong with my code. would you guys mind checking it.

my php page has an index.php which is the main menu, if you click the employee name in the list, a pop up window will appear. that pop up is for updating.

my php code (it now updating) but errors found:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','pss') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('intra',$con);

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gpl_employees_list where emp_id='".$_POST['eid']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
                            {                       
                                return false;
                            }

    $qry = "UPDATE gpl_employees_list SET emp_nme = '".$_POST['ename']."', emp_pos = '".$_POST['pos']."', emp_dep = '".$_POST['dep']."', emp_tag = '".$_POST['tag']."' WHERE emp_id = '".$_POST['eid']."' ";  

    mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error()); 
?><script>window.close();</script><?php 
        }       
    ?>
```

*NOTE : this is now updating, but if a user leaves one of the textboxes empty, it updates the table with empty spaces as well and that is my problem now. how do i avoid that? i mean if a user leaves one textbox empty,the data with empty values must still contain its old value,but how to do that with this code? thanks for those who will help

```
MisaChan
```

Comment: Pleeeeease make sure you sanity check that input, or better yet, use a parameter in your query, before using this.  You are begging for an SQL injection attack with that code.  You need to do a preg_match() on the emp data, and ideally use SELECT * FROM gpl_employees_list WHERE emp_id = ?; for your query.

Comment: @King Skippus : i already changed my code, please refer to Sir CleaverQuack's post, thats the same code i used now almost, although there is still a little error

Comment: The input still needs to be sanitized.  Never ever pass input provided by a user straight into the query.  Please read this, especially the "Mitigation" section at the bottom: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use $_POST for 'name/pos/dep/tag' and $_GET for 'emp' so you're probably not getting the values.
Change the GETs to POST - that should do it.
Since you're updating, I'd recommend using POST over GET.
GET is more appropriate for searching.

Also, you can put all your update queries into one update query.
Like so.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pos = $_POST['pos'];
$dep = $_POST['dep'];
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
$emp = $_POST['emp'];

$qry_start = "UPDATE gpl_employees_list SET ";
$where = " WHERE emp_id = $emp";
$fields = "";
$updates = "";

if($name){
  $updates .= " `emp_name` = $name,";
}
if($pos){
  $updates .= " `emp_pos` = $pos,";
}
if($dep){
  $updates .= " `emp_dep` = $dep,";
}
if($tag){
  $updates .= " `emp_tag` = $tag,";
}
$updates = substr($updates, 0, -1); //To get rid of the trailing comma.
$qry = $qry_start . $updates . $where;
```

Comment: @CleverQuack : thanks for the reply. this following errors appeared `Notice: Undefined index: emp in C:\wamp\www\Intranet_Update\empinfo.php on line 85

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\Intranet_Update\empinfo.php on line 86

Notice: Undefined index: pos in C:\wamp\www\Intranet_Update\empinfo.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined index: dep in C:\wamp\www\Intranet_Update\empinfo.php on line 88

Notice: Undefined index: pos in C:\wamp\www\Intranet_Update\empinfo.php on line 89`

Comment: @MisaChan In order to use the `$_POST` superglobal, you need to submit a POST request, usually from a form.

Comment: i commented the code i put on my post and changed it with yours, but these errors appeared. this caused the error: ` $emp = $_POST['emp'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $pos = $_POST['pos'];
  $dep = $_POST['dep'];
  $tag = $_POST['pos'];`   i already tried that before, same error appeared

Comment: @MisaChan My code won't work unless you change the "method" of the form being submitted; just like @Phil said. Gotta change it to POST first. --- Also note that my code is complete code, just a sample to try and help. You need to call the query afterwards.

Comment: @Phil : there is a POST method in my form located at my index.php, on my codes listed above, when i tried to echo the value that was passed **$_GET[emp']** , it echoes the emp of the clicked linked. but it wont update once you click on the  submit button. also, there is no error founf on my code :(

Comment: @CleverQuack and @Phil : i already changed my GET to POST, but the same error i said above shows. which are the `$emp = $_POST['emp']; $name = $_POST['name']; $pos = $_POST['pos']; $dep = $_POST['dep']; $tag = $_POST['pos'];`

Comment: We're referring to the form that the user fills out. What method is it using?

Comment: @CleverQuack : i am using the POST method in my form, i used GET in the emp since it came from the index.php (which is the passed value, i am also trying to figure out what could be the cause of the error, i edited your code and no error is found now,im going to check if it updates

Comment: @CleverQuack: it is now updating, but my worries already appeared. if the textbox is empty, the update page is also empty. i would like it to be like this, the update page contains name,pos,dep and tag right? if the user wants to only update dep,meaning there would be empty spaces in the name,pos and tag. The original content should remain and only the field with content updates.im going to post here the codes i used

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
  $qry = "UPDATE gpl_employees_list SET emp_nme = '".$_POST['name']."', emp_pos = '".$_POST['pos']."', emp_dep = '".$_POST['dep']."', emp_tag = '".$_POST['tag']."' WHERE emp_id = '".$_GET['emp']."' ";  
  mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
  }`

Comment: @MisaChan Glad to hear that you've got it working. I understand what you're trying to do, I'll edit my answer to show a way to do that...

Comment: @CleaverQuack : i tried the code but it did not update, il try to rearrange it though, honestly i am not familiar with the pattern you set :)) i did not know this is posible

Comment: Ya sorry for being a little fast/sloppy. I just have some other work that really needs my full attention. If you can wait, I'd gladly help you in more detail later. :)

Comment: @CleverQuack : sure i am more than willing to wait :) i am happy that you're trying to help me here. i will still try to work on it and update you for the results or findings i make with this program :)

Comment: @CleverQuack : i cant find any solution to my previous problem, but i think i found what cause it. i created a select before the update first, and then a query,the problem i guess is the `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))` because when i tried to `echo $row['emp_nme'];` to test it,nothing appears. i hope you can answer it :( by the way its already updating, but empty spaces are updated as empty spaces and not the original value :( i will wait for the answer, thanks

Comment: Hey. I'm back. Ugh, what a night last night. Anyways, I've edited to the code in my answer to be good/valid code. Sorry I was in too much of a rush last night to give you better code then.

Comment: @CleverQuack : i don't know why but nothing happen in the code. but i have fixed my code yesterday which updates, but then it updates the code with "empty spaces" someone told me to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` but i don't know which conditions to put.i will put what i have worked on yesterday. would you mind checking it? thanks :)

Comment: @MisaChan To make it so you don't put in "empty spaces" you need to dynamically created your update query based on what values are entered. That's what my code does. It does not actually execute the query, it just creates the query to execute. put a `$result = mysql_query($qry);` after that and it should work fine.

Comment: @Clever Quack, i already solved it finally :) using trim? i got help from someone

Answer (score 1):

this is what i used to keep it working :) i hope this could be a source for others as well :)

```
$col['emp_nme'] = (trim($_POST['ename']))?trim($_POST['ename']):false;
$col['emp_pos']  = (trim($_POST['pos']))?trim($_POST['pos']):false;
$col['emp_dep']  = (trim($_POST['dep']))?trim($_POST['dep']):false;
$col['emp_tag']  = (trim($_POST['tag']))?trim($_POST['tag']):false;
// add a val in $col[] with key=column name for each corresponding $_POST val

$queryString ="UPDATE `gpl_employees_list` SET ";
foreach($col as $key => $val){
if($val){
    $queryString .="`".$key."`='".$val."',";
}
                            }
$queryString = substr($queryString ,0 ,strlen($queryString) - 1 )." WHERE emp_id = '".$_POST['eid']."'"; 
mysql_query($queryString);
```

Comment: Yes that's a good way to do it too. I'm a fan of foreach loops myself. Though I would have appreciated some love by marking me as an answer rather than yourself. :P

Comment: gomen ne desu :P ok! is it ok to check to answers? :P

Comment: would you mind voting my question and answer up as well? i think it will help me earn some reputation here :) il gladly vote up you post as well :)

Comment: Arigato gozaimasu sir @ CleverQuack :) till next time

Answer (score 0):

After making changes to an SQL database, remember to commit those changes, otherwise they'll be ignored.

Comment: Whilst true, I doubt this is the problem. PHP's MySQL library is set to auto-commit by default

Comment: Ah, OK, I didn't know that. (I would've thought it would be safer for it not to auto-commit by default.)

Comment: Postgres also auto-commits by default.  AFAIK, that's pretty common in the OSS database world.