# Problem with MySQL update

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [table updates empty spaces when user do not enter anything to the textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182253/table-updates-empty-spaces-when-user-do-not-enter-anything-to-the-textbox)

greetings :)

i am having problems updating my database whenever the user clicks on the submit button.
i am going to show you the flow of my program,i already tried figuring out the problem,but i just can't find solutions. i hope someone could help me.

i have 2 problems encountered here:

1. my database won't update after clicking the submit button
2. the user may choose which to update,if the textbox is empty,it will update the data with empty spaces.and i want the data to remain as it is if the textbox is empty.

in my program,if you want to update the employee information,you must click the name that contains a link in the page. (in my program its the employee name that needs to be clicked) when clicked,a pop up will open.

the link in my index.php contains the following code:

```
<td class="sub" width="100" align="center">
  <a href="" onclick = javascript:newPopup('empinfo.php?emp=<?php echo $eid ?>');><?php echo$ename?></a>
    </td>
```

*NOTE* the empinfo.php is my pop up window,it calls the pop up when clicked. emp isthe name i assign to pass in the empinfo.php it contains the employee ID. *NO PROBLEM HERE,I JUST WANT TO SHOW YOU THE FLOW*

when the empinfo.php appears,it will show this format:

```
Employee name: //textbox here
Position:      /textbox here
Department:    /textbox here
Employee Tag:  /textbox here
**SUBMIT BUTTON**
```

when the user clicks the submit button, it should have updated the database with the inputted values,but mine won't update :(

here is the codes i used:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','mariel') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('intranet',$con);
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
    $qry = "UPDATE gpl_employees_list SET emp_nme = '".$_POST['name']."', emp_pos = '".$_POST['pos']."', emp_dep = '".$_POST['dep']."', emp_tag = '".$_POST['tag']."' WHERE emp_id = '".$_GET['emp']."' ";  
    mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

this is the content code in my form,together with the submit that i used:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='eid' id='eid' value= '<?php echo $_GET['emp']?>' />  

<fieldset>
            <div class='container'>
                <label for='ename' >Employee name:</label><br/>
                <input type='text' name='ename' id='ename' value='' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
             </div>

             <div class='container'>
                <label for='pos' >Position:</label><br/>
                <input type='text' name='pos' id='pos' value='' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
             </div>

            <div class='container'>
                <label for='dep' >Department/Division:</label><br/>
                <input type='text' name='dep' id='dep' value='' maxlength="100" /><br/><br/>
            </div>

            <div class='container'>
                <label for='tag' >Employee Tag:</label><br/>
                <select name="tag" id="tag">
                    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                    <option value="N">No</option>
                </select> <br/><br/>
            </div>

            <div class='container'>
                <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' onclick = "location.reload();window.close()"/>
            </div>
</fieldset>     
</form>
```

i hope someone could clear it up for me

**MisaChan**

Comment: what's your form code look like? sanitize your query too to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: 1) sanitize that query!! 2) what's the form in the code? is the $_POST['submitted'] really submitted?

Comment: i am going to add it on top of my post, i used method="POST" in my form. @Damien Pirsy : my post_submitted isn't the submit button, its a hidden textbox

Comment: Hello, [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @tradyblix and @Damien Pirsy: i already added my form code, i am not that good yet in using php since i am still a student, so sorry if i question much

Comment: @MisaChan Your form action is 'index.php', where does the php for elaborating the form resides? in 'index.php' or in 'empinfo.php' ?

Comment: @Dasmien Pirsy: the form code is in the empinfo.php as well. and @OMG Ponies : i dont think i have duplicated any codes. cause what you see on top is hte empinfo.php code as it is, i just did not put the minor and obvious codes here cause i want to keep it straight to the point

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of things wrong, but these points should help you debug your script.

- Firstly you need to [escape your post
  variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to ensure things like
  apostrophes don't mess up your query,
  it's also a security vulnerability.
- Secondly, make sure your form action is pointing to the PHP script. Maybe put a print statement at the top of the script to make sure PHP is actually receiving the data.
- Then assign the value of the SQL query to a variable and print it out before you run it. You can then easily see what's being sent to the SQL server. Maybe run it in an SQL management tool my phpMyAdmin and observe any errors with it.

Hope this helps. Feel free to update your question with new information as it comes.

Comment: i am always using the POST variables because it always give me an unknown _variable_ when a assign it to a variable, i also used another way but it seems that it still wont update my database,it was taught to me by someone who said i should try it out,can you point out what could have cause my error?i think its in my empinfo.php code

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant your form action. You need to point your form to the right place using action="empinfo.php".

Comment: my form is in the empinfo.php, you mean, instead of index.php in the action, i should put empinfo.php?

Comment: Your form action should point to the script. Look at tradyblix's answer, that should fix it up.

Comment: the code in tradyblix is the same as mine, does it mean i should use POST rather than GET? and i tried to used echo to check if it gets the value, and it does

Answer (score 1):

It's not updating because you probably need to refer to `$_POST['eid']` instead of `$_GET['emp']` because you don't have it in `index.php` like `index.php?emp=1`. You already have that field so use that:

```
<input type='hidden' name='eid' id='eid' value= '<?php echo $_GET['emp']?>' />
```

Also you don't need to do this:

```
onclick = "location.reload();window.close()"
```

Type submit reloads the page by default.
Lastly, consider @**Sam152**'s pointers :)

Comment: Ah yes, that looks right. He is passing the ID with GET to the page with the form and then passing it with POST to the script. Updating the script to WHERE emp_id = '".$_POST['emp']."'" should fix it. +1

Comment: @tradyblix : the problem is if i remove the onclick, the empinfo.php wont close since this is a pop up, on the 1st code, do you mean i should put POST rather than GET in the emp??

Comment: @MisaChan : You are assigning `<?php echo $_GET['emp']?>` to a field name called `eid` so when you submit, "emp" will be on `$_POST['eid']`. For your window close, you can probably do a check after submitting: `<?php if ($_POST['submitted']) {?><script>window.close();</script><?php } ?>`, try it out and play around with it, but that's the idea.

Comment: @tradyblix : i did what you said, and this is what happen. i only put values in the name,the pos and dep are all empty spaces and when i clicked the submit button,it now update,but the name,pos,and dep contains empty spaces T-T it did not even inputted the value i typed in the name textbox :( what should i do

Comment: @MisaChan, it's because you're using `$_POST['name']` but your field is `ename` so you should change that to `name` instead

Comment: @tradyblix, i tried removing the `value=''` but the same result appears. the name, pos and dep contains empty values in the database :(

Comment: @MisaChan, ignore that, see my new comment

Comment: @tradyflix : the name already updated :) my problem 1 is solved! but my 2nd problem is still there, since the user is given free will to updated whatever he/she wants, he/she my leave some textbox blank.and whenever a textbox is empty,it should still contain the original data stored,should i put conditions in it?

Comment: @MisaChan, probably do a separate query before updating. Do a `SELECT` if `submitted` is present to get the original values, then check each of the submitted fields for empty fields, if there's empty, get the orignal values from the `SELECT` you did to keep it, may probably work.

Comment: @tradyblix : so you mean i should do `SELECT` first before update in the same if `submitted`?? because i tried creating conditions like the one im going to comment here next, BUT there was an error,the line its referring to is the `$eid=$_POST['eid'];` `Notice: Undefined index: eid in C:\wamp\www\Intranet_Update\empinfo.php on line 111`

Comment: here are the conditions i used: `$eid = $_POST['eid'];
  
  if(empty($_POST['ename']))
  {
  $ename = "SELECT emp_nme FROM gpl_employees_list WHERE emp_id='".$eid."'";
  }
  else
  {
  $ename = $_POST['ename'];
  }
  
  if(empty($_POST['pos']))
  {
  $epos = "SELECT emp_pos FROM gpl_employees_list WHERE emp_id='".$eid."'";
  }
  else
  {
  $epos = $_POST['pos'];
  }
  
  if(empty($_POST['dep']))
  {
  $edep = "SELECT emp_dep FROM gpl_employees_list WHERE emp_id='".$eid."'";
  }
  else
  {
  $edep = $_POST['dep'];
  }`

Comment: @MisaChan, whoa whoa..hold it there..do a `SELECT` that has it all e.g. `SELECT emp_pos, emp_name, whatever, etc FROM your_table WHERE emp_id = id`..you get the idea. Try to figure out the rest, I got work to do too :)

Comment: @tradyblix, ok il try to do so, il update you for the results :)

Comment: @tradyblix, may i ask you one last thing? saying that you SELECT all of the data in the table, and you want to use it, how could i do that? i am planning to use an if conditions to test if ins empty,but i am not sure how to use values inside the table

Comment: @MisaChan, After selecting you need to fetch the rows: php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @tradyblix : i did put that `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);` following by the conditions i made inside a bracket